# Android studio structural replace not deleting old code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am using structural replace in android to replace some lines in my code. Let's say I want to replace all `line-A`s with `line-B`s. 
I am able to successfully find the lines using an existing search template but when I trigger replace, its not exactly replacing the `line-A` with `line-B` but pasting `line-B` in place of `line-A` and shifting `line-A` one line below it.

This is what's happening :

```
| line-A |  ===>  | line-B |

                  | line-A |  // This is extra.
```

What I want is this :

```
| line-A |  ===>  | line-B |
```

I don't see any option in the replace dialog which gives an option to enable/disable this behaviour.

Please help.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of what you are searching for and with what you are trying to replace?